# Application freezes when logging in and out a few times through passport.js (node express app)

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, passport.js, facebook-oauth

So I know that it's unlikely that the user will do this but....

if a user visits the web app they can sign in under one of two groups, both of which use passport.js to sign in. Group A uses local and LinkedIn while Group B uses Google and Facebook.

When logging in its fine and logging out is ok with the following get:

```
 router.get('/logout', function (req, res){
    req.flash('success_msg', 'you have logged out');
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
```

but If i ever try to log back in under a different Oauth (like do linkedIn and logout and then do google and logout, and then try facebook) the application will freeze either right before or right after the `passport.deserializeUser` method gets called. Is this to be expected?

Answer (score 0):

So after some critical thinking I realized that the reason that no error was being call was because there was no error, things were just going slow.

SO for anyone out there using a my-sql in your node app **make sure** that you pool your connection and **make sure** that you release it when you're done.

nice little tutorial [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections)